# Prevent emission if the same emission occurred x milliseconds ago

Tags: rxjs, rx-java, system.reactive, rx-android

I would like to prevent an emission from occurring if and only if the same exact item was emitted within the last x milliseconds. I've looked at the throttle and debounce operators but I'm not sure if they can help me here. Is there another operator I can use, or can I compose them somehow?

Comment: Can you provide more info? For example what objects are you working with, how fast are the items emitted? Where do you emit those items from? Is it important for you those items are emitted one by one, or can they be emitted in batch?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with groupByUntil to essentially debounce individual items

```
o
  .groupByUntil(x => x, x => x, x => Observable.timer(1000))
  .flatMap(grp => grp.first())
```

Comment: That's how I would do it.

Comment: Looks good for RxJS -- RxJava2 doesn't seem to have the groupByUntil operator, shoot :)

Comment: yeah wasn't sure why you listed both rxjs and rx-java.  You can try porting the C# version to Java: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/Rx.NET/blob/83710cfa9395355af6eb908f96261ea632a49009/Rx.NET/Source/src/System.Reactive/Linq/Observable/GroupByUntil.cs

Comment: For millisecond ranges of time, this isn't very GC efficient.

Comment: @Asti hard to say without knowing throughput. Any solution requires allocations to "remember" elements which have come before and when they came, which means all solutions will cause some amount of GC pressure

Answer (score 1):

You could timestamp and pair off each item, and then check your boundary conditions of time and equality.

```
   randomSource
                .timestamp()
                .pairwise()
                .where(pair => pair[0].timestamp - pair[1].timestamp < limit && pair[0].value === pair[1].value);
```

Then apply a `.select(pair => pair[0].value)` to get back your original item.

Working example in C#, with a source that generates random items between 1 and 5 spaced over random times:

```
    static IObservable<T[]> Pairwise<T>(this IObservable<T> source)
    {
        source = source.Publish().RefCount();
        return source.Skip(1).Zip(source, (a, b) => new[] { a, b });
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var randomSource =
            Observable.Defer(() => Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(new Random().NextDouble() * 2))).Repeat().Publish().RefCount().Select(_ => new Random().Next(1, 5));

        var limit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        var sameDebounce =
        randomSource
            .Timestamp()
            .Pairwise()
            .Where(pair => pair[0].Timestamp - pair[1].Timestamp < limit && pair[0].Value == pair[1].Value);


        sameDebounce.Subscribe(c => Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", c[0], c[1]));
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
```

Output:

```
2@9/7/2017 5:00:04 AM +00:00 2@9/7/2017 5:00:04 AM +00:00
2@9/7/2017 5:00:09 AM +00:00 2@9/7/2017 5:00:08 AM +00:00
1@9/7/2017 5:00:23 AM +00:00 1@9/7/2017 5:00:23 AM +00:00
2@9/7/2017 5:00:33 AM +00:00 2@9/7/2017 5:00:32 AM +00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

As your question does not completely explains the scenario like compare next emitted value to last emitted value or any last emitted values or something else. 
I would take a general way to reach to the solution.

Example is in **RxJava**.

You can use `timestamp()` with `filter()` operator like following:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        final long[] timeOfSubscribe = {-1};
        final long timeDuration = 2 * 1000; // 2 seconds
        Observable.fromIterable(list)
                .timestamp()
                .filter(item -> item.time() > (timeDuration + timeOfSubscribe[0]) && item.value().equals("your last value"))
                .doOnSubscribe(__ -> timeOfSubscribe[0] = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis())
                .subscribe();
```

I guess this snippet can help you just need to change your emitted value comparison login that is in `filter()` operator. If you are looking for last emitted value you can stop last emitted value using `doOnNext()` operator (to have simple case) or if your looking for all the last emitted values you need to store emitted values in list and check.

I hope it helps.